# HP Pavilion DV7 using Windows Vista will not recognize blank DVD

Tags: windows-vista, dvd-burning

When inserting a blank DVD into the Optiarc BD ROM BC-5500 SATA drive on a HP Pavilion DV7-1273CL, using Windows Vista (64 bit), it will not recognize the disc.

It says drivers are up to date, but I have uninstalled and reinstalled. I've rebooted and set low and high filters in registry and rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

Cgheck drive capabilities:
http://www.vso-software.fr/products/inspector/inspector.php

Your drive has to WRITE particular media type to accept a blank disk. Say it would be happily reading recorded DVD-RAM-DL, while not having the writing laser for DL or -RAM.

Also speed ratings matter.

Answer (score 0):

Optical drives have firmware where it stores CD and DVD types, if it is an older drive it may not have the media type for a newer brand of disc, so it cannot read it, a firmware update usually cures it, but most OEM's (especially HP) do not keep up with providing firmware updates for optical drives, [check the HP website for your specific model](http://www8.hp.com/us/en/support-drivers.html) of notebook to see if there are any firmware updates for your specific model of optical drive.

Here is an example of firmware for a Sony optical drive, as you can see the list of media types hard coded into the optical drive's firmware.

I am not saying this is your problem but is the most common issue when other reasons for it not reading new discs cannot be found.

.
[image]